# Token Based Authentication MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I currently have an app built in MVC 5 that uses individual authentication and has Web API access if the user is authenticated within the browser using their username and password.

I am looking to now add in the ability for Token based authentication so that users can GET and POST data to my app from other applications they utilize. I have been searching forums but unable to find a great method that explains the entire process.

Does anyone have any tutorials for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JWTs. This is a fast and secure way to let users authenticate and act securely with the APIs of your solution

[see here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)